# criterion for lower and upper semi continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

In nonlinear functional analysis course I a studying proper, lower semicontinuous and bounded below functions. I read different criterias for lowersemicontinuous functions, for instance 1) lim inf f(x) at a >=f(a) 2) lim f(x) >= f(a)
 3) lim inf f(x)= (min {f(a+), f(a-))>= f(a). lim inf also has many criterion. will someone give me a simpler criterion for lim inf, lim sup, lower semi cont, upper semi cont ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functional analysis, convex optimization and analysis etc, lower semi-continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ is defined as
$$
x_n \to x \ \Rightarrow f(x)\le \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)
$$
(if everything is happening in a metric space). See also

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity